# macでlua付きのvimをインストールしたいが、Error: invalid option: --with-luaというエラーが発生する

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, lua

MacOS Mojaveでbrewを使ってlua付きのvimをインストールしたいです。

ターミナルで

```
brew install vim --with-lua
```

と打ったところ、

```
Error: invalid option: --with-lua
```

というエラーが表示されてしまいます。
そこで、`brew info vim`で利用可能なビルドオプションを確認したところ、

```
vim: stable 8.1.1150 (bottled), HEAD
Vi 'workalike' with many additional features
https://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with:
  ex-vi (because vim and ex-vi both install bin/ex and bin/view)
  macvim (because vim and macvim both install vi* binaries)
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gettext ✔, lua ✘, perl ✘, python ✘, ruby ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 70,013 (30 days), 205,299 (90 days), 823,322 (365 days)
install_on_request: 64,165 (30 days), 187,214 (90 days), 722,299 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

と表示され、`--with-lua`がビルドオプションにないことがわかりました。
どのようにすればビルドオプションを追加することができるのでしょうか？
または、lua付きのvimをインストールすることができる他の方法はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: [既存のvimをluaオプション付きのvim8.0に入れ替える。](https://qiita.com/Fendo181/items/8a5545cd7550bd9a3c91) とか [vimをlua付きで再インストールする際にエラーが出た時の対処](https://qiita.com/nishiys/items/03c4f4c2651a996bf779) が参考になるのでは？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いつからだったか，Lua はデフォルトで有効になっています． brew install vim または brew install macvim でインストールした後，vim --version で確認してみてください

Comment: Xcodeインストールする前にbrewでvimをインストールしたことが問題だったみたいです。Xcodeインストール後にbrew、vimともに再インストールしたところ、luaが有効になってました。ありがとうございます。